# How to use getopt/OPTARG in Python? How to shift arguments if too many arguments (9) are given?

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-interface, getopt

How to use getopt/optarg in Python?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is an example of how I do it, I usually use the same basic template:

```py
import sys
import getopt

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'm:p:h', ['miner=', 'params=', 'help'])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    elif opt in ('-m', '--miner'):
        miner_name = arg
    elif opt in ('-p', '--params'):
        params = arg
    else:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
```

I don't think there is any 9 parameter limit.

Comment: "argv" needs to be "sys.argv"

Comment: You need to slice off the script name from the `argv` array like: arvg[1:] for this line to work:
`opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], 'm:p:h', ['miner=', 'params=', 'help'])`

Comment: what usage() function used to ?

Answer (score 13):

A google search would have helped. Have a look at the [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) and [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) modules in the standard library:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

Then run it as expected:

```
$ prog.py -h
usage: prog.py [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]

Process some integers.

positional arguments:
 N           an integer for the accumulator

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --sum       sum the integers (default: find the max)
```

When run with the appropriate arguments, it prints either the sum or the max of the command-line integers:

```
$ prog.py 1 2 3 4
4

$ prog.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
10
```

This is straight from the standard library.

Comment: Argparse and its tutorial are awesome.

Comment: Sorry for the add but I would suggest you have a look for `docopt` before diving into `argparse`...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried reading the python docs for the module `getopt` (http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html?highlight=getopt#module-getopt)? It provides a simple example of how the `getopt` is used. What do you mean by shift arguments? If you want to check that the user does not use more than 9 arguments, you can check the length of the `sys.argv` list, which contains all the options/arguments passed to the script. The first element is the name of the script which is invoked, so the length is always at least 1. You could do something like:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 10
    print('Too many arguments.')
```