# Is there a method to pass in my own CLI switches to a unittest file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unittest

If you call the program below with python filename.py -d abc you get unittest help.  If you call filename.py /d abc you get:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '/d'

I'd like to create my own CLI switches.  To specify config file or some such CLI switch.  I've tried --d as well.  Is there a method for unittest to accept allow other switches?

```
import unittest

class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        theTest( 'keith' )

    def test_two(self):
        otherTest( 'keith')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main( argv=sys.argv, testRunner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys` and `getopt` modules to parse command-line options and arguments, allowing you to use short and long options (e.g. -x and --long-option).

Comment: How is this mixed with unittest since unittest still seams to balk at any additional flags.

Comment: Add code to **parse args** with `for` loop and for each arg you will do something (e.g. set a variable or run some code). Check out [How to use getopt/OPTARG in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382804/how-to-use-getopt-optarg-in-python-how-to-shift-arguments-if-too-many-arguments)

Comment: Figured it out.  You call parse_known_args() without any arguments.  It passes back two lists.  parsed args and unparsed args (or additional args).  Unfortunately unit test removed arg[0] so I just put it back.  This is exactly what I needed to make unit test happy.